# How to check Current version of React using command prompt

Tags: reactjs

I installed Reactjs using npm command creat-react-app. Now I want to check which version I installed

Answer (score 9):

Just type the below command in your command prompt:

```
npm view react version
```

Example:

[image: Command Prompt]

There are multiple ways to check react version in your project:
[6 Different ways to Check React Version | Terminal](https://codezup.com/6-different-ways-to-check-react-version-terminal/)

Comment: This is wrong, it lists the latest React version from the NPM registry. It does not list the version currently installed in the local directory. Use @Brian Thompsons's solution for that.

Comment: This answer is not wrong, but yes it lists the latest React version from the NPM registry. But as per the question the user want to know the installed version of react in their machine. Anyways, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7):

Run the command `npm list react` or `npm ls react` from the root directory of your project. [Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html).

Answer (score 0):

A great place to check for which version of React you have installed is in the package.json, which should be under node_modules/react/index.js

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! This would likely be better suited as a comment, as you are pointing the user to a reference, rather than catering to their issue specifically.

Comment: @DavidChopin interesting.. Thanks for the help! Shoot, just trying to build my way TO make comments lol.

Comment: Thanks for your help I got it. is there any command to know the version without entering the project folder?  I mean get the version from the global packages list since it installs globally.